# Alternative to x.innerHTML for long texts

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a form in HTML and JS that shows at the end the completed form uneditable for confirmation.

I have to replace the contents of the page without refresh and/or redirection.

My code is:

```
function F() {
    if(...){
         //Empty fields [...]
     }else{
        var el = document.getElementById("formID"); //Form da sostituire
        el.innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "new content" is really long and is very uncomfortable to write it as a string. Are there any alternatives to innerHTML for this situation?

Comment: what do you expect to write it as , I mean html is a string ?

Comment: Well you could store the `NEW CONTENT` in a variable at top of code or something where you don't want to see it (or even in a separate .js file)

Comment: @MarkoMackic In the line el.innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT"; I think that "NEW CONTENT" is a String...

Comment: @yuriy636 I don't want to use Strings!

Comment: You want a string :) just you don't want to store it in ugly way.

Comment: @Calaf You asked for "any alternatives to innerHTML for this situation", not my fault that you didn't say that you don't want to use strings.

Comment: @MarkoMackic I think that the solution proposed by Gondo is better. Templates aren't strings, but the result is what I wanted.

Comment: Excuse me if I have not been able to better expose the problem. I thought that writing "is very uncomfortable to write it as a string." You would understand what I meant.

Comment: Then you don't understand definition of string, and I don't know how to clarify to you, what you get from `template.innerHtml` is a string, it doesn't matter if that's html. That's what I was trying to say. No problem :) I understood

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag. Put the content you want inside a `<template>` tag, give it an ID, and then in JavaScript simply copy the content of the template inside the form.

HTML:

```
<template id="form-template">
  NEW CONTENT
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
function F() {
    if(...){
         //Empty fields [...]
     }else{
        var el = document.getElementById("formID"); //Form da sostituire
        el.innerHTML = document.getElementById("form-template").innerHTML;
    }
}
```

See live example in the following snippet:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", event => {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("my-template").innerHTML
})
```

```html
<template id="my-template">
  <h1>Hello template!</h1>
</template>
<button type="button">Try it!</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For problem of `<template>` browser support you could use any element as placeholder, like this :

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", event => {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("my-template").innerHTML
})
```

```css
.template{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-template" class="template">
  <h1>Hello template!</h1>
</div>
<button type="button">Try it!</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Or just give `display:none` to template element :)